# Jasper Reports - Subreport - Blank page between title and detail bands

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm working on a subreport in Jasper Reports and its detail can get rather large, more than a page in length on its own.  What I'm having trouble doing is getting it to print right after the summary paragraph.  It always leaves a blank page in between the title band and the detail band and then prints.  When it then prints, it prints on more than a page.  It's under this scenario (detail table/band larger than one page) that it leaves the unnecessary blank buffer page.

Here's a picture of the report that gets generated, to help explain what's happening. (Sorry about the blacked out text, I don't want to get in trouble for divulging anything).

[image]

Here is a picture of the band layout for the subreport:

[image]

**Root Question:**

How can I make it so that the detail prints as close as possible to the summary paragraph? Instead of deciding to skip the current page, leave an additional blank page, and then print.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How high is the title band relative to the rest of the report?  You may need to create a report that does what you are seeing without the confidential information, then post that to pastebin or here for review.

Comment: @IsraelLopez How high is the title band?  Such as compared to the previous content that printed before it did?  It's not far.  20px or so.

Comment: Just increase the height of the report and try